# How to have React Router links inside child react components

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm struggling with what I'm sure is the basics of React Router. I have an overall App.js file, and a child react functional component, Navbar.js. I want my Switch to be in App.js, but Navbar.js to have Links to my different pages.

The questions I looked at previously dealing with nesting talked about nested routes, but I don't think that is my case here. Do I need to declare a new route in the Navbar component? I'm a little confused as to why I can't just have the link component on its own in Navbar, or just push the page I want to history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, So you just need to import what we call as a Link from react-router-dom.

And then you can use Link as an "anchor" tag

```
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
 <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a benefit to using <Li nk to=> tags instead of pushing it onto history, `history.push('/some/path')`?

Comment: @BigSteve `history.push('/some/path')` is meant to navigate pragmatically, like after completing an API request, `link` is meant to be used for a button just meant to navigate.

Answer (score 0):

In App.js you can have the `switch`

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route path="/contact-us" component={ContactUs}/>
        ....
    </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And in the Navbar.js you can have the navigation

```
<div>
    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
    <Link to="/contact-us">Contact us</Link>
    .....
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! And the entirety of App.js should be wrapped in a BrowserRouter?

Comment: The `routes` need to be wrapped in a `BrowserRouter` (see my updated answer)

Comment: Does the <routes> tag need to encompass the child component holding the <link> tags?

Comment: @BigSteve No, both the `<route>` and `<link>` elements need to be inside the `<BrowserRouter>` element.

Comment: Do so the <route> and <link> could be inside the <BrowserRouter> through the composition of components? Like could the <route> and <link> components be in a component thats a child component of a component with the <BrowserRouter> tag?

Comment: @Bigsteve Yes, THe `<Route>` and `<Link>` components need to be within the `<browserRouter>` component, but it doesn't need to be a direct child of the `<borwserRouter>` component.